# Sitecore logs full with WARN Datakey length bigger then 100 chars, and was trimmed

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

We are having some problems with the following line in the log files of Sitecore:

```
WARN  Datakey length bigger then 100 chars, and was trimmed
```

It's not really a massive problem, but it is logging this up to 2000 times in one day.

If I have investigated further: probably it has got something to do with the DataKey column in the analytics database. I know there is a limitation to 100 characters. But if we could find out what code adds a datakey that is to large we can fix it.

Anyone got an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in your Analytics database and then look at the PageEvents table you'll see the DataKey in this table.

Take a look at the values in this field  - it will more than likely be an exception occurring. The data key will have the details of the exception.

Comment: Apparently it where logs that we were making ourselves, every Log.Error gets logged to there, and these weren't under 100 chars. Thanks